# Restoring wordpress site using .zip and .sql onto AWS

Tags: mysql, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

What is the best was to restore a website from a backup when all I have is a .zip file and a .sql file of the wordpress site migrating onto aws. So far I tried installing wordpress with a EC2 instance of wordpress and I was going to try and restore from the dashboard using a wordpress plugin. But no plugin I found can upload a .sql database like I thought. Which doesn't make much sense now that I really think about it. I am unsure if should I install a Microsoft SQL Server DB Instance in RDS or MySyl for the wordpress install? Please help so confused...

Answer (score 0):

You can use that method:

1. Extract the wp-content folder and upload it.
2. Log onto your ec2 and use the mysql command line to import the database.
3. Update the siteurl and home in wp_options.

Comment: also I am unsure where the backend is to upload the wp-content folder. I just have it on a static IP and am able to login to the dashboard but not sure where the files are kept on aws. Do I need to add a S3 bucket and link it to the static IP?

Comment: No, you dont need an s3 unless the wp-content is large, in which case you can mount an s3 on the filesystem. Use sftp to put the files directly on the ec2. Some of the bitnami WP AMIs have a different file structure, but the WP install is usually located in /var/www/html. You'll need to setup your ftp client with the server key and username.

Comment: still on number 2. I was not able to transfer it said transfer incomplete. There is a wordpress>htdocs>wp-contents folder in 2 folders stack and apps. Not sure if I have a permissions settings wrong or if I am trying to put it in the wrong place.

Comment: Oh nevermind I found that I need to change the permissions in SSH